# Cancel delegate call after FB returned and delegate has been dealloc'd

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm posting to a users Facebook wall with code similar to this:

```
[appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
              andParams:params
          andHttpMethod:@"POST"
            andDelegate:self];
```

If I dismiss the hosting UIViewController before the request completes, I get a crash when the request does actually complete because the delegate has been dealloc'd.

There's a good description of the problem I'm facing here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/220

```
- (void)dealloc {
appDelegate.facebook.sessionDelegate = nil;
[super dealloc];
```

}

This does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a solution for that but not very convenient;

I am having 2 separate views in the same view controller, where one of them is the one you request the publish the other the destination view.

You just hide one of the views when request is finished. Or hide the other and display the one while requesting.

For example if you are going to another page after logging in :

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
// Do necessary stuff
           self.secondView.hidden = YES;
           self.view.hidden = NO;
}
```

The idea is like that, it works but not very convenient.

Comment: Does this solve the issue when the views are deallocated while the request is not yet finished?

Comment: As you have the views in your rootView, or mainView which are not deallocated before the application quits, there is no problem with deallocation here.

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to save the FBRequest object when you call the GraphAPI.
So you will be able to set it's delegate property to nil when your class is being dealloced.
Thus cleaning up your mess and avoid crash caused by the SDK's respondsToSelector method.

First declare a FBRequest property in your class.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) FBRequest *fbRequest;
```

Synthesize it in your class.m:

```
@synthesize fbRequest;
```

Set it when you call the graph API as so:

```
fbRequest = [appDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
              andParams:params
          andHttpMethod:@"POST"
            andDelegate:self];
```

Set it's delegate propery to nil on your class's dealloc method:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    fbRequest.delegate = nil;
    [fbRequest release];
    .
    .
    .

    [super dealloc]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object (separate from the view controller) that will be the FB delegate and don't deallocate that.  You could instantiate it from the same place you instantiate the view controller that calls FB.
Or, if you don't care about the return status, don't use a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how Facebook's own code deals with this in Facebook.m they create a list to hold _request objects 'NSMutableSet* _requests;'

and this is alloc/init'd & the requests added as you make calls then they remove them all when cleaning up.
See the lines with '  [_requests addObject:_request];' and look at dealloc where you will see:-

```
  for (FBRequest* _request in _requests) 
{
_request.delegate = nil;
[_request removeObserver:self forKeyPath:requestFinishedKeyPath];
 }
```

I used this approach in my own FB code to nil the delegates & it stopped the crashes I was having when exiting while a request was active.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to overcome this problem is to create a wrapping class for FB which I called "FacebookManager". It is a singleton in charge of every FB request done along your application. Being a singleton app-wide, it's life cycle lasts also for the whole app life too.

```
@protocol
@optional
-(void)fbDidLogin;
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;
-(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt;
-(void)fbDidLogout;
-(void)fbSessionInvalidated;
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;

@end

@interface FacebookManager : Facebook <FBSessionDelegate, FBRequestDelegate>

+(FacebookManager *)sharedFacebookInstance;
-(void)setFacebookDelegate:(id)delegate;
-(void)requestWithGraphPath:(NSString *)fbPath;
```

Other classes, usually ViewControllers, can be FacebookManager's delegate (or, if needed, you can make an array of delegates when processing concurrent requests). When FacebookManager receives the response from the request, it passes this along to the original class.
Ans since it's the sole delegate for every FB request and never deallocates through your program, even when the original class is dealloc'ed, no errors will arise.

As a bonus to all this, you automatically lose those warning for the methods you need not implement if not desired.

Hope this helps in any way!